# Sending data from FPGA to PC via Ethernet

Tags: fpga, ethernet

I am implementing an Ethernet module using an FPGA board, and currently, I'm struggling with the transmitter.

Right now, I use hardcoded data that are sent to the PC. According to the IEEE standard (802.3-2018), I have assembled a vector consisting of the following fields:

- 7 byte preamble: 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
- 1 byte SFD: 0xAB
- The MAC address of my Ethernet port
- The MAC address of the board
- The field Length, for which I use the minimum value of 46
- 46 byte of random data
- A 32 bit CRC

With that configuration and with the help of Wireshark, I fail to see any packets arriving on my computer.

Furthermore, I connected two FPGA boards via Ethernet, and the data were sent and received normally, which I probably mean that at least my module is interacting correctly with the PHY.

Any ideas or suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Ethernet interface, driver, or sniffer on your PC is probably dropping bad packets or packets not correctly addressed to your PC.

For example, for certain Intel Ethernet adapters on Windows, you need a registry setting to be able to receive those packets. [Info from Intel is here.](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005498/network-and-i-o/ethernet-products.html)

Comment: Thanks for replying.

I checked the statistics using the Linux ip command and there are no dropped packets.

Comment: There are lots of places between your PC's Ethernet adapter and packet sniffer where packets can be dropped, and the 'ip' command isn't showing you stats for all of them.

Comment: Are you receiving packets from the PC? Try looping them back and see what happens.